# In Ffmpeg-Python how to merge Audio Track with keeping the Existing Audio Track and Subtitles

Tags: python

import ffmpeg

video = ffmpeg.input('input.mkv').video

audio = ffmpeg.input('audio.mp3').audio

ffmpeg.output(video, audio, 'output.mkv', vcodec='copy', acodec='copy').run()

What i need to do with this code for merging new audio track with existing audio and subtitles.

Please Help me with this Thanks!